# Meaning of statement "elif" in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

In the following code i want to know what exactly is the meaning of the elif statement.I know that if the "if" statement gives false then the statements in the "elif" statement will occur .However i wanna know exactly which is the false condition from the "if" statement(if it is false).Is being continued in my comment

```
def find_Biggest():      
#function definition
    if(a>b) and (a>c):
        largest=a
    elif(b>a) and (b>c):
        largest=b
    else:
        largest=c
```

The condition in the "if" statement is `(a>b and a>c)`.If this condition is false it means that either `a<b` either `a<c` or `(a<b and a<c)` right? So,the condition in the following "elif" must be the opposite of thaf condition..Which is the opposite of this condition?Sorry if i confused you i didn't mean to but though i can solve this easy example i wanna understand the inner mechanism of the if -elif..thank you very much.

Comment: add the explanation in post not in comments

Comment: Sorry but it didn't allow me to.

Comment: It doesn't .I'm browsing this site on smart phone.It just keeps on  cutting off the rest of my post everytime i try.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it is the same as if there was `else if`. One very important difference, though: it is there to solve the so called [Dangling else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) problem. In particular, the problem in itself is solved by Python's white-space sensitive syntax, but the parser disallows `else if` syntax because of it.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the mentioned condition in the "if" clause is false,it will move forward to "elif" it does't matter now what were the condition earlier,it will simply check the new conditions. If all conditions are true(in elif) it will simply execute the statements.It is not an issue of being opposite to "if".

Answer (score 0):

elif is the python equivalent of "else if".

Comment: Exactly .However "else" means "if the above condition is not true i.e if the above condition was x>=0 then it means that in the "else" statement the variable x is being considered below 0

Comment: when "If" is false it "checks" if "elif" is true, if both "if" and "elif" are false only then "else" is run. Hope that clears any confusion up

Answer (score 0):

`elif` means that execution will happen **if and only** if the conditions above it are **not** satisfied and the `elif` itself **is** satisfied - it is like a *switch*/*case* statement in plain English some programming languages. It will also *not* goto to the `else` condition in this case.

Here you are checking if `a` is the biggest - if so it marks it - otherwise it checks if `b` is the biggest and mark it; otherwise it marks `c` as the biggest (even if it tied with `a` or `b`).

More specifically, if `a>b and a>c` is false that just means `a` is **not** the biggest (it could be tied with `b` or `c`, but that is not enough). Similarly if `b>a and b>c` is false, that means `b is not the biggest` (again tie is not enough). If both are false, it marks `c` as the biggest even if it is tied.

Comment: It may be good to mention that if the `elif` statement is satisfied, the code within the `elif` is executed, and the `else` statement will not be executed.